# Python Beautifulsoup: Unable to select element despite of it's there

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am parsing information from [this](https://www.redfin.com/CA/San-Francisco/3418-26th-St-94110/unit-2/home/56802406) page. If you scroll down you will find Energy Score section on left which is `66` here. The HTML I see it is like that:

```
<div class="energyContentContainer" data-reactid="9"><div class="RadialMeter fair inline-block energyDataRadial" data-reactid="10"><div class="viz" data-reactid="11"><div class="circle" data-reactid="12"><div class="mask full" style="-webkit-transform:rotate(118.8deg);transform:rotate(118.8deg);" data-reactid="13"><div class="fill" style="-webkit-transform:rotate(118.8deg);transform:rotate(118.8deg);" data-reactid="14"></div></div><div class="mask half" data-reactid="15"><div class="fill" style="-webkit-transform:rotate(118.8deg);transform:rotate(118.8deg);" data-reactid="16"></div></div><div class="shadow" data-reactid="17"></div></div><div class="inset" data-reactid="18"></div></div><div class="RadialMeterContent" data-reactid="19"><div class="percentage" data-rf-test-name="ws-percentage" data-reactid="20">66</div><div class="iconAndLabel" data-reactid="21"><div class="label" data-reactid="22"><div class="flyoutLabelWrapper" data-reactid="23"><span class="linklessLabel" data-reactid="24">Energy Score</span><noscript data-reactid="25"></noscript><span data-rf-test-name="flyout-transition-group" data-reactid="26"></span></div></div></div></div></div><div class="energyComparisons" data-reactid="27"><span class="how-score-compares-text" data-reactid="28">How your energy score compares</span><div class="lockedSectionBanner" data-reactid="29"><div class="icon" data-reactid="30"><svg class="SvgIcon rfSvg secure" style="fill:black;height:24px;width:24px;" data-reactid="31"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#secure"></use></svg></div><div class="message" data-reactid="32"><span data-reactid="33"><p data-reactid="34">Claim this home to unlock comparisons</p><div class="claimHomeButton notSubscribed unclaimed" data-reactid="35"><a href="#" class="Button med v3 tertiary-alt v3" data-name="Subscribe" tabindex="0" data-reactid="36"><span data-reactid="37">I'm the Owner</span></a></div></span></div></div></div><div class="rec-wrapper" data-reactid="38"><h4 class="rec-expenses" data-reactid="39"><!-- react-text: 40 -->This home spends an estimated <!-- /react-text --><span class="rec-expense-amount" data-reactid="41"><!-- react-text: 42 -->$<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 43 -->74<!-- /react-text --></span><!-- react-text: 44 -->/month on energy. Want to lower your bill?<!-- /react-text --></h4><span class="Solar" data-reactid="45"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#585858" d="M12 5.4c-3.6 0-6.5 2.9-6.5 6.5s2.9 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5-2.9 6.5-6.5c0-3.5-2.9-6.5-6.5-6.5zm0 2c2.5 0 4.6 2 4.6 4.6s-2 4.6-4.6 4.6-4.6-2-4.6-4.6S9.5 7.4 12 7.4zM11.9 0c-.4 0-.7.3-.7.6V4c0 .2.1.4.4.5.2.1.5.1.8 0 .2-.1.4-.3.4-.5V.6c0-.2-.1-.3-.2-.4s-.5-.2-.7-.2zM11.9 19.5c-.4 0-.7.3-.7.6v3.4c0 .2.1.4.4.5.2.1.5.1.8 0 .2-.1.4-.3.4-.5v-3.4c0-.2-.1-.3-.2-.4-.3-.2-.5-.2-.7-.2zM3.5 3.6c-.3.3-.3.7-.1.8l2.4 2.4c.1.2.3.2.6.1.2-.1.4-.3.5-.5s.1-.5-.1-.6L4.4 3.4c-.1-.1-.2-.2-.4-.1-.2 0-.4.1-.5.3zM17.2 17.4c-.2.3-.2.6 0 .8l2.4 2.4c.1.1.4.2.6.1s.4-.3.5-.5c.1-.2.1-.5-.1-.6l-2.4-2.4c-.1-.1-.2-.2-.4-.2s-.4.2-.6.4zM0 12.1c0 .4.3.7.6.7H4c.2 0 .4-.1.5-.4.1-.2.1-.5 0-.8-.1-.2-.3-.4-.5-.4H.6c-.2 0-.3.1-.4.2s-.2.5-.2.7zM19.5 12.1c0 .4.3.7.6.7h3.4c.2 0 .4-.1.5-.4.1-.2.1-.5 0-.8-.1-.2-.3-.4-.5-.4h-3.4c-.2 0-.3.1-.4.2-.2.3-.2.5-.2.7zM3.6 20.5c.3.3.7.3.9.1l2.4-2.4c.1-.1.1-.3 0-.6-.1-.2-.3-.4-.5-.5-.3-.1-.5-.1-.6.1l-2.4 2.4c-.1.1-.2.3-.1.5 0 .1.1.3.3.4zM17.4 6.8c.3.2.6.2.8 0l2.4-2.4c.1-.1.2-.4.1-.6-.1-.2-.3-.4-.5-.5-.2-.1-.5-.1-.6.1l-2.4 2.4c-.1.1-.2.2-.2.4s.2.4.4.6z"></path></svg></span><div class="rec-title" data-reactid="46">Consider Solar Panels For Your Roof</div><div class="rec-savings" data-reactid="47"><!-- react-text: 48 -->$<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 49 -->1026<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 50 --> savings/year<!-- /react-text --></div><div class="rec-description" data-reactid="51"><!-- react-text: 52 -->Even with upfront costs, solar power will save the average American around $20,000 over a 20 year period. Local and federal rebates can increase savings even more<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 53 -->.<!-- /react-text --></div><a href="http://www.servicemagic.com/ext/32271520" class="Button  tertiary v3 rec-button" tabindex="0" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" data-reactid="54"><span data-reactid="55">Get a Quote</span></a></div></div>
```

If I do following then it's not picking correct element. I tried to check view source and found out that this is not a dynamic element either.

```
energy_section = soup.select('.energyContentContainer .RadialMeterContent')
```

and it returns `[]`

What wrong am I doing?

Comment: I can't find any instances of "energyContentContainer" in that source - are you sure you have the right class name?

Comment: I think you missed a comma

Answer (score 0):

I think you're calling function correctly, you might just have the wrong class name or the wrong URL to test with. Here's an example that shows it working as you expect with the sample data you've posted:

```
>>> import bs4
>>> htmldoc = """<div class="RadialMeterContent" data-reactid="19"><div class="percentage" data-rf-test-name="ws-percentage" data-reactid="20">66</div><div class="iconAndLabel" data-reactid="21"><div class="label" data-reactid="22"><div class="flyoutLabelWrapper" data-reactid="23"><span class="linklessLabel" data-reactid="24">Energy Score</span><noscript data-reactid="25"></noscript><span data-rf-test-name="flyout-transition-group" data-reactid="26"></span></div></div></div></div>"""
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmldoc, "html.parser")
>>> soup.select('.RadialMeterContent')
[<div class="RadialMeterContent" data-reactid="19"><div class="percentage" data-reactid="20" data-rf-test-name="ws-percentage">66</div><div class="iconAndLabel" data-reactid="21"><div class="label" data-reactid="22"><div class="flyoutLabelWrapper" data-reactid="23"><span class="linklessLabel" data-reactid="24">Energy Score</span><noscript data-reactid="25"></noscript><span data-reactid="26" data-rf-test-name="flyout-transition-group"></span></div></div></div></div>]
>>> soup.select('.RadialMeterContent .percentage')
[<div class="percentage" data-reactid="20" data-rf-test-name="ws-percentage">66</div>]
```

I can't find any instances of the text "energyContentContainer" when I view source on the URL you posted. Nor can I see an Energy Score section.

Okay, here's an example with your updated HTML snippet:

```
>>> htmldoc = """<div class="energyContentContainer" data-reactid="9"><div class="RadialMeter fair inline-block energyDataRadial" data-reactid="10"><div class="viz" data-reactid="11"><div class="circle" data-reactid="12"><div class="mask full" style="-webkit-transform:rotate(118.8deg);transform:rotate(118.8deg);" data-reactid="13"><div class="fill" style="-webkit-transform:rotate(118.8deg);transform:rotate(118.8deg);" data-reactid="14"></div></div><div class="mask half" data-reactid="15"><div class="fill" style="-webkit-transform:rotate(118.8deg);transform:rotate(118.8deg);" data-reactid="16"></div></div><div class="shadow" data-reactid="17"></div></div><div class="inset" data-reactid="18"></div></div><div class="RadialMeterContent" data-reactid="19"><div class="percentage" data-rf-test-name="ws-percentage" data-reactid="20">66</div><div class="iconAndLabel" data-reactid="21"><div class="label" data-reactid="22"><div class="flyoutLabelWrapper" data-reactid="23"><span class="linklessLabel" data-reactid="24">Energy Score</span><noscript data-reactid="25"></noscript><span data-rf-test-name="flyout-transition-group" data-reactid="26"></span></div></div></div></div></div><div class="energyComparisons" data-reactid="27"><span class="how-score-compares-text" data-reactid="28">How your energy score compares</span><div class="lockedSectionBanner" data-reactid="29"><div class="icon" data-reactid="30"><svg class="SvgIcon rfSvg secure" style="fill:black;height:24px;width:24px;" data-reactid="31"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#secure"></use></svg></div><div class="message" data-reactid="32"><span data-reactid="33"><p data-reactid="34">Claim this home to unlock comparisons</p><div class="claimHomeButton notSubscribed unclaimed" data-reactid="35"><a href="#" class="Button med v3 tertiary-alt v3" data-name="Subscribe" tabindex="0" data-reactid="36"><span data-reactid="37">I'm the Owner</span></a></div></span></div></div></div><div class="rec-wrapper" data-reactid="38"><h4 class="rec-expenses" data-reactid="39"><!-- react-text: 40 -->This home spends an estimated <!-- /react-text --><span class="rec-expense-amount" data-reactid="41"><!-- react-text: 42 -->$<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 43 -->74<!-- /react-text --></span><!-- react-text: 44 -->/month on energy. Want to lower your bill?<!-- /react-text --></h4><span class="Solar" data-reactid="45"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#585858" d="M12 5.4c-3.6 0-6.5 2.9-6.5 6.5s2.9 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5-2.9 6.5-6.5c0-3.5-2.9-6.5-6.5-6.5zm0 2c2.5 0 4.6 2 4.6 4.6s-2 4.6-4.6 4.6-4.6-2-4.6-4.6S9.5 7.4 12 7.4zM11.9 0c-.4 0-.7.3-.7.6V4c0 .2.1.4.4.5.2.1.5.1.8 0 .2-.1.4-.3.4-.5V.6c0-.2-.1-.3-.2-.4s-.5-.2-.7-.2zM11.9 19.5c-.4 0-.7.3-.7.6v3.4c0 .2.1.4.4.5.2.1.5.1.8 0 .2-.1.4-.3.4-.5v-3.4c0-.2-.1-.3-.2-.4-.3-.2-.5-.2-.7-.2zM3.5 3.6c-.3.3-.3.7-.1.8l2.4 2.4c.1.2.3.2.6.1.2-.1.4-.3.5-.5s.1-.5-.1-.6L4.4 3.4c-.1-.1-.2-.2-.4-.1-.2 0-.4.1-.5.3zM17.2 17.4c-.2.3-.2.6 0 .8l2.4 2.4c.1.1.4.2.6.1s.4-.3.5-.5c.1-.2.1-.5-.1-.6l-2.4-2.4c-.1-.1-.2-.2-.4-.2s-.4.2-.6.4zM0 12.1c0 .4.3.7.6.7H4c.2 0 .4-.1.5-.4.1-.2.1-.5 0-.8-.1-.2-.3-.4-.5-.4H.6c-.2 0-.3.1-.4.2s-.2.5-.2.7zM19.5 12.1c0 .4.3.7.6.7h3.4c.2 0 .4-.1.5-.4.1-.2.1-.5 0-.8-.1-.2-.3-.4-.5-.4h-3.4c-.2 0-.3.1-.4.2-.2.3-.2.5-.2.7zM3.6 20.5c.3.3.7.3.9.1l2.4-2.4c.1-.1.1-.3 0-.6-.1-.2-.3-.4-.5-.5-.3-.1-.5-.1-.6.1l-2.4 2.4c-.1.1-.2.3-.1.5 0 .1.1.3.3.4zM17.4 6.8c.3.2.6.2.8 0l2.4-2.4c.1-.1.2-.4.1-.6-.1-.2-.3-.4-.5-.5-.2-.1-.5-.1-.6.1l-2.4 2.4c-.1.1-.2.2-.2.4s.2.4.4.6z"></path></svg></span><div class="rec-title" data-reactid="46">Consider Solar Panels For Your Roof</div><div class="rec-savings" data-reactid="47"><!-- react-text: 48 -->$<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 49 -->1026<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 50 --> savings/year<!-- /react-text --></div><div class="rec-description" data-reactid="51"><!-- react-text: 52 -->Even with upfront costs, solar power will save the average American around $20,000 over a 20 year period. Local and federal rebates can increase savings even more<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 53 -->.<!-- /react-text --></div><a href="http://www.servicemagic.com/ext/32271520" class="Button  tertiary v3 rec-button" tabindex="0" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" data-reactid="54"><span data-reactid="55">Get a Quote</span></a></div></div>"""
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmldoc, "html.parser")
>>> soup.select('.energyContentContainer .RadialMeterContent')
[<div class="RadialMeterContent" data-reactid="19"><div class="percentage" data-reactid="20" data-rf-test-name="ws-percentage">66</div><div class="iconAndLabel" data-reactid="21"><div class="label" data-reactid="22"><div class="flyoutLabelWrapper" data-reactid="23"><span class="linklessLabel" data-reactid="24">Energy Score</span><noscript data-reactid="25"></noscript><span data-reactid="26" data-rf-test-name="flyout-transition-group"></span></div></div></div></div>]
```

To get the desired value, try something like:

```
>>> soup.select_one('.energyContentContainer .RadialMeterContent .percentage').text
u'66'
```

Comment: Means is it being loaded dynamically.?

Comment: But when I do view-source:https://www.redfin.com/CA/San-Francisco/3418-26th-St-94110/unit-2/home/56802406 in Chrome it does show `energyContentContainer`

Comment: Not for me. If you can post the relevant snippet I can help you with the `soup.select` call

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. Can you select the parent div and copy it's contents, then edit your question and paste it in there?

Comment: I already did that in original question but you say you can't see it at all.

Comment: Thanks. Now your code works though - is it working for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143237/discussion-between-peter-gibson-and-volatil3).